# Multiple ArrayLists(Portfolios) of an Object(Stock) that allows the stock to have different quantities in different portfolios

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a custom "Stock" class with instance variables as such:

```
public class Stock
{
    // Instance variables
    private String company;
    private double value;
    private int quantity;
}
```

and a "Portfolio" class with instance variables:

```
public class Portfolio
{
    // Instance variables
    private ArrayList<Stock> portfolio;
    private String name;
}
```

Currently, I have the issue that when creating multiple portfolios that editing the quantity of a stock in one portfolio it also changes the quantity in the other portfolio. I know this is because the same reference to the stock is being stored in both portfolios.

I want to know is there a implementation where I can have multiple portfolios where changing the value of the stock will change in every portfolio but I can change the quantities of a stock per portfolio.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some object-oriented analysis should reveal that the quantity held is not an attribute of the `Stock` itself.  It is not a part of the portfolio itself, because there can be different quantities for different stocks.  I would remove `quantity` from `Stock`.

I would introduce a `Holding` class that has a `Stock` attribute and a quantity.  I would also have the `Portfolio` class have a `List<Holding>`.  Different `Portfolio`s can have different `Holding` objects, each of which may or may not refer to the same `Stock` object with different quantities.  This would allow you and I to each own Google stock with different quantities, for example.